# How do I copy a range as a picture to a UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I need to display images located in cells in every row of column A (using a for/next loop) in a UserForm (images would change to the next row with a button). The issue is that i don't want to refer every image by their name, i basically want to say :

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
 Sheets(x).Range("A" & i).Copy
```

And then paste that with the picture in that cell (like a snapshot of the cell) into a UserForm (could be textbox or label or picture, anything...).

How could I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-get-a-range-as-a-picture-on-a-userform.991390/

Comment: How would i make it run for every cell in the first column of the sheet (loop would happen on clicking the button). I tried many ways but it does not work...

Comment: I modified this `Set oSelection = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)`

Comment: And that `Private Sub LoadSelectionIntoImgOnUserForm()
  Dim frm As F_PicRangeIntoImage
  lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
  
  Set frm = F_PicRangeIntoImage
  For i = 2 To lRow
  With frm
    .Show
  End With
  Unload frm
  Next i
End Sub`

Comment: But i keep getting errors...

Comment: "errors" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code, and not anything we can use to help suggest a fix.  What's the exact error, and on which line of code?